# Swift 3 - Time Part of Date And Different Timezones

Tags: swift, date, timezone

I am having an issue with a date string received from a REST web service and how that is being represented in Swift in different timezones. I have just been able to reproduce this issue, so I am going to relate this specific example.

The information I am getting from the web service is a date-time string and a timezone identifier. In this case, the system is in the **America/New_York** or Eastern US timezone. I created a playground where I have the following code

```
let dateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
let easternTimeZone = "America/New_York"
let serverDate = "2017-03-01T00:00:00-05:00"
```

I have a method that takes the date string and the timezone identifier and creates a Date object as follows

```
func dateForDateString(dateString: String, timeZone: String) -> Date?
{
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    if timeZone != ""
    {
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZone)
    }

    formatter.dateFormat = dateFormatString

    return formatter.date(from: dateString)
}
```

When I call this method with what's returned from the web service

```
let easternDate = dateForDateString(dateString: serverDate, timeZone: easternTimeZone)
print("\(easternDate)")
```

The `print` statement outputs `Optional(2017-03-01 05:00:00 +0000)` which is expected. No problems yet. The problem happens when the device is in a different timezone and for the sake of this example, I am testing with Pacific time. In the playground, the `easternTime` variable shows as `Feb 28, 2017, 9:00 PM`. Again, not unexpected.

The date is going to be stored in a Firebase database and I don't care about the time at all. So I end up using the `Calendar` method `startOfDay` as follows

```
let myDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: ed)
```

as you may expect, this returns the Date `Feb 28, 2017, 12:00 AM`. Obviously not what I want to store in Firebase. The bottom line is that I need the date to be in the timezone the web service returned.

**UPDATE**
As mentioned in the comments, I also tried to create a Calendar instance and set it's timeZone property to a TimeZone with the identifier received from the server. The code looks like this

```
var easternCal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
if let etz = TimeZone(identifier: easternTimeZone)
{
    easternCal.timeZone = etz
}

if let ed = easternDate
{
    let convertedDate = dateToTimeZone(date: ed, toTimezone: easternTimeZone)
    let currentCalDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: ed)
    let myDate = easternCal.startOfDay(for: ed)
    print("\(myDate)")
}
```

Last night, I could have sworn this didn't work, but when I try it now in the playground, it appears to be working just fine. `currentCalDate` is the date I don't want, `Feb 28, 2017, 12:00 AM` since it is using the user's Calendar that has the Pacific timezone set. `myDate` is correctly showing as `Feb 28, 2017, 9:00 PM`, which is printing as `2017-03-01 05:00:00 +0000`, what I have wanted all along.

I think this one is solved.

Comment: Did you try to convert all time to UTCTime and save to Firebase with UTC time?

Comment: FYI - there is no reason at all to be passing in a timezone string and setting the date formatter's timezone when parsing the string into a date since the `serverDate` string already specifies its timezone offset (the `-05:00` part).

Comment: `Calendar` also has a `timeZone` property.  You probably need to set that as well.

Comment: @MattJohnson I have tried creating a calendar with the timezone identifier received from the server and using that Calendar to call startOfDay and I get the same results. I'll update the post with that code.

Comment: @MattJohnson If you write up an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't code much in Swift. I'll leave that to you or someone else.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the update to my question, creating a Calendar instance and setting the `timeZone` property to the one returned from the back-end solved my problem.

Comment: I had no idea that you could "localize" `startOfDay` by changing the time zone of the calendar. I didn't even realize a calendar had a time zone!